# An error has occurred because a control with id {0} could not be located or a different control is assigned to the same ID after postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, viewstate

I have a site that consists of an ajax driven menu, administration.aspx, and several linked pages in this menu.

Somtimes though, the navigation between them seems to be broken. For instance, when situated at `LayoutSettings.cs`, clicking `Countries.cs` just causes `LayoutSettings.cs` to reload (but `Countries.cs` can be reached from other pages on the site).

No error message gets displayed, but upon setting a breakpoint in `Global.asax.cs.Application_Error()`, I notice that the following is happening:

> Application error: System.Web.HttpException (0x80004005): English translation: An error has occurred because a control with id ctl00$SiteContentPlaceHolder$ctl00$ctl01 could not be located or a different control is assigned to the same ID after postback. If the ID is not assigned, explicitly set the ID property of controls that raise postback events to avoid this error.

I can't see anything suspicious in the markup for either link in the administration.aspx files. I also don't see any controls in the LayoutSettings and Countries.cs files with duplicate names (or unassigned names). What can I try from now on? As best as I can tell, ViewState is enabled.

I would gladly share relevant code, but I'm not sure exactly what should be included just yet.

Comment: Do you have something like  string.Format("property: {0}", value)  where the actual value is missing?

Comment: Are you using NameSpace for any of your Pages? perhaps the `Countries.aspx` page should preface with your names space btw,  `NameSpace.Countries.cs` in the header section of the .aspx page. can you show the header of the aspx page and the header snippet of the .cs file..?

Comment: MrFox: I did not find any string.Format without the actual value. DJ KRAZE: All these pages are have Namespace=Telerik.Web.UI". What exactly is the header snippet of the .cs? Sorry for not quite understanding, but all this help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you generate any controls dynamically?