# "Control with id could not be located or a different control is assigned to the same ID after postback." Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-grid

I have a `web-application` in `.NET framework 4.5` with code behind `C#`.

I am using a `RadGrid` of `telerik Asp.Net Ajax control`. I am creating it `dynamically` from `code behind` in `PageInit` event and adding it to a `div` that is `statically` defined in aspx file.

Now, for each row I am having a `button` that is used to expand and collapse the row using `JQuery` script.

I also have a `RadCalendar` on the page and I am fetching records according to selected date range.

Now, the problem is, if I select a date range from **1st to 16** days, it works fine. If I select **1st to 30** days then also there is no problem. But now if I select **1st to 8**, it gives me the error show below :

```
Server Error in '/' Application.
An error has occurred because a control with id 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$gvGridViewDemo$ctl00$ctl09$Detail20$ctl06$Detail10$ctl04$ctl10' could not be located or a different control is assigned to the same ID after postback. If the ID is not assigned, explicitly set the ID property of controls that raise postback events to avoid this error.
```

I am **NOT** using any `ajax` in this page, so on date selection it gets **full postback**. Also I had set `viewstate to false`, `ViewstateMode to disable` and `ClientId = autoId` for both - `Button` and `Gridview`. But I am not able to get rid of this.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this ridicules error?

P.S. I have checked the link [An error has occurred because a control with id {0} could not be located or a different control is assigned to the same ID after postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051995/an-error-has-occurred-because-a-control-with-id-0-could-not-be-located-or-a-di) and according to the comment I am having string.format() in my code. But I have commented it and still I am facing the same issue.

Comment: I suggest you set breakpoints to your codes and debug . Also please view your html markup and check whether there is a control whose ID matches one of the IDs your are trying to generate

Comment: I did it but did not got any error. I tried all the possible debugging and then I came here for solution.

Comment: Did you check your html markup?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved it by myself. I do not consider it to be the great solution I have discovered but I am answering this question that it might help someone who wants to get rid of this kind of issue and tired of finding the exact solution.

I have solved it by debugging skills with Trial and Error methodology (it requires so much patience in oneself).

What I did is, I started commenting some of the code that places dynamic controls on the page and checked for result whether the same error is generated or not? If yes, then you are commenting wrong code. So just remove the comments, make that portion as it was and move on.

At last I found that there were some dynamically generated tool-tips; I was used to display some additional details on every cell of the grid view (RadGrid), were creating this error. On PageInit I was clearing all of the controls of the division and adding a grid view by code behind. So each time the request gets initiated, it clears all of the controls and adds them newly.

However, the objects of tool-tip (I have used RadTooltip to display the tool-tip on cell) were not getting cleared from the page across the postbacks.

So I just applied a new ID to each tool-tip using its cell's (cell of grid) `client id + DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString()`, and I kicked off myself from this weird error.

Answer (score 0):

I see you solved it, yet this may be useful in the future if you have problems with RadTooltip, I had a couple of issues resolved with this: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/tooltip-troubleshooting-common-issues.html.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this problem too. What fixed it was explicitly adding ID values to all the Control objects I was dynamically loading onto my screen.

Answer (score 0):

It happens for me when I have multiple command field in my grid view. I converted them to template fields and everything worked fine!